# Korean translation in Globalization Pipeline

Tags: translation, ibm-cloud, globalization-pipeline

What's the relative quality level of Korean translation in [IBM Globalization Pipeline](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/11/17/translate-bluemix-apps-using-globalization-pipeline/)?

"Invalid usage" is translated to "효력이 없는 사용", but when I send this:

```
Invalid usage (extra arguments), try {name1}{name2}
```

I get:

```
.  {name1} {name2}
```

For all the other languages (`es`, `fr`, `de`, `it`, `ja`, `pt-BR`, `zh-Hans`, `zh-Hant`), the results look reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when variable parameters are involved, output could be very poor. At this moment, the service depends on generic machine translation engines running on backend, translation results are not really optimized for incomplete sentences.

Comment: Thanks, but why only Korean returns the poor result?  For all the other languages, results look reasonable.